# Adding extra argument to xargs

Tags: shell, xargs

I'm trying to kick off multiple processes to work through some test suites. In my bash script I have the following

`printf "%s\0" "${SUITE_ARRAY[@]}" | xargs -P 2 -0 bash -c 'run_test_suite "$@" ${EXTRA_ARG}'`

Below is the defined script, cut down to it's basics.

SUITE_ARRAY will be a list of suites that may have 1 or more, {Suite 1, Suite 2, ..., Suite n}
EXTRA_ARG will be like a specific name to store values in another script

```
#!/bin/bash

run_test_suite(){
    suite=$1
    someArg=$2
    someSaveDir=someArg"/"suite
    # some preprocess work happens here, but isn't relevant to running
    runSomeScript.sh suite someSaveDir
}

export -f run_test_suite

SUITES=$1
EXTRA_ARG=$2

IFS=','
SUITECOUNT=0
for csuite in ${SUITES}; do
    SUITE_ARRAY[$SUITECOUNT]=$csuite
    SUITECOUNT=$(($SUITECOUNT+1))
done
unset IFS

printf "%s\0" "${SUITE_ARRAY[@]}" | xargs -P 2 -0 bash -c 'run_test_suite "$@" ${EXTRA_ARG}'
```

The issue I'm having is how to get the `${EXTRA_ARG}` passed into xargs. From how I've come to understand it, xargs will take whatever is piped into it, so the way I have it doesn't seem correct.

Any suggestions on how to correctly pass the values? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please specify how many values are typically in `${SUITE_ARRAY[@]}`, and also whether `${EXTRA_ARG}` is meant to be used once is is to be a recurring value for `$someArg`.

Comment: `${SUITE_ARRAY[@]}` may vary from run to run; as little as 2 to as many as 20+. `$someArg` would remain the same for each call, but when the main script that the xargs is in is called, the `${EXTRA_ARG}` could be different.

Comment: Edited the question and code a bit to reflect your comments.

Comment: Typo in my prior comment, hereby corrected:  Please specify how many values are typically in `${SUITE_ARRAY[@]}`, and also whether `${EXTRA_ARG}` is meant to be used once, or is is to be a recurring value for `$someArg`.

Comment: `export EXTRA_ARG`

Comment: That said, `SUITE_ARRAY=$1` is assigning it as a string, not an array, so `"${SUITE_ARRAY[@]}"` makes no sense. What's the *actual* exact value of `$1` that you want to have parsed into an array?

Comment: (Also, note that all-caps names are defined as used by variables with meaning to the shell itself, or to POSIX-specified utilities, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `EXTRA_ARG` to be available to the subshell, you need to `export` it. You can do that either explicitly, with the `export` keyword, or by putting the `var=value` assignment in the same simple command as `xargs` itself:

```
#!/bin/bash

run_test_suite(){
    suite=$1
    someArg=$2
    someSaveDir=someArg"/"suite
    # some preprocess work happens here, but isn't relevant to running
    runSomeScript.sh suite someSaveDir
}
export -f run_test_suite

# assuming that the "array" in $1 is comma-separated:
IFS=, read -r -a suite_array <<<"$1"

# see the EXTRA_ARG="$2" just before xargs on the same line; this exports the variable
printf "%s\0" "${suite_array[@]}" | \
  EXTRA_ARG="$2" xargs -P 2 -0 bash -c 'run_test_suite "$@" "${EXTRA_ARG}"' _
```

The `_` prevents the first argument passed from `xargs` to `bash` from becoming `$0`, and thus not included in `"$@"`.

Note also that I changed `"${suite_array[@]}"` to be assigned by splitting `$1` on commas. This or something like it (you could use `IFS=$'\n'` to split on newlines instead, for example) is necessary, as `$1` **cannot** contain a literal array; every shell command-line argument is only a single string.

Comment: You're right about the assignment from `$1`. In my haste in posting up my code, I left out the part where I'm breaking the `$1`, which is a comma separated argument "suite 1,suite 2, suite 3,...,suite n" into an array. I honestly don't know shell well enough to break up easily, so I use a for loop. I'll update the question again.

Comment: The code here using `read -a` is the correct way to parse a string into an array.

Comment: Looks like this method worked best, however I discovered if I passed in only 1 value in the array, the `-P` would kick off 2 processes with the same one argument. I was expecting it to only kick off 1. I worked around this by checking if the array was 2 or greater, if so, let `-P` be 2 otherwise use 1.

Comment: @EmmanuelF, ...which version of xargs? I can't reproduce that; `printf '%s\n' 1 2 | xargs -P 2 -n 2 bash -c 'echo "$$: $*"' _`, for example, does what I'd expect.

Comment: Charles, I had initially set up like this `printf "%s\0" "${suite_array[@]}" | ARG="$EXTRA_ARG" xargs -P 2 -n 1 -0 bash -c 'run_test_suite "$@" "${ARG}"' _` and for some reason the run_test_suite ran twice when I only passed in 1 arg. I ran your snippet above and saw it only ran once. I wonder what I did wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

This is something of a guess:

```
#!/bin/bash

run_test_suite(){
    suite="$1"
    someArg="$2"
    someSaveDir="${someArg}/${suite}"
    # some preprocess work happens here, but isn't relevant to running
    runSomeScript.sh "${suite}" "${someSaveDir}"
}

export -f run_test_suite

SUITE_ARRAY="$1"
EXTRA_ARG="$2"

printf "%s\0" "${SUITE_ARRAY[@]}" | 
xargs -n 1 -I '{}' -P 2 -0 bash -c 'run_test_suite {} '"${EXTRA_ARG}"
```

Comment: The inner quotes *close* the outer ones. And the `-n 1` and `-I` are bad practice here -- it means `xargs` runs a new copy of bash for each item, which the original code didn't do.

Comment: ...by "close the outer ones", I mean that the string `{}` is unquoted here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, Thanks, the bad quotes were a hasty typo, now corrected, perhaps...  The `-n 1` is deliberate, and a *guess* as to the OPs actual intentions based on the code and [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163197/adding-extra-param-to-xarg/49183275?noredirect=1#comment85364030_49163197).

Comment: Ugh, [now we learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163197/adding-extra-param-to-xarg/49183275?noredirect=1#comment85379519_49184459) the "array" is a comma separated string, stored as an actual `bash` array?     Ah well, my code requires that the array is just an array, containing no delimiting commas.

Comment: I know, I'm sorry. I was trying to get this up with the parts I felt were most relevant to the question at hand. Again, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

run_test_suite(){
    suite="$1"
    someArg="$2"
    someSaveDir="$someArg"/"$suite"
    # some preprocess work happens here, but isn't relevant to running                        
    echo runSomeScript.sh "$suite" "$someSaveDir"
}
export -f run_test_suite

EXTRA_ARG="$2"
parallel -d, -q run_test_suite {} "$EXTRA_ARG" ::: "$1"
```

Called as:

```
mytester 'suite 1,suite  2,suite "three"' 'extra "quoted" args here'
```

If you have the suites in an array:

```
parallel -q run_test_suite {} "$EXTRA_ARG" ::: "${SUITE_ARRAY[@]}"
```

Added bonus: Any output from the jobs will not be mixed, so you will not have to deal with http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Using_output_from_xargs_-P